# jQuery if iframe with class exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to detect if iframe with specific class exists, but its not working for me.

I need to detect if iframe with chat exists on site https://gaming.youtube.com for one of my scripts. Its weird that in this demo it can detect iframe: http://jsfiddle.net/t7qMF/13/ but when you go to any live stream on https://gaming.youtube.com, you can not detect if the iframe with chat exists.

When I use `$("iframe.class");` it returns the iframe, but when I try `$("iframe.class").length;` I get `undefined`.

I tried googling, but everybody is saying to use `element.length`, which is just not working for me. It actually returns undefined even when I just use `$("iframe").length`

Here is screen of my console where its not working:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I'd very surprised if this was, in fact, the case; can you produce a test case/demo that reproduces the described behaviour?

Comment: I'll edit the question and tell what I am trying to do.

Comment: Chrome has it's own built-in helper function in the console called `$`, which is a shortcut for `document.querySelector`. Try doing `jQuery("iframe.class")` in the console.

Comment: Ok, now I feel dumb :D My script was not loading on the site and I did not notice it, as I am injecting jquery there with my script... Fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `$` is not always jQuery. In Chrome dev console, when jQuery is not available, it is alias to [document.querySelector()](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#selector)

Comment: Which would still report a length property. Or at least it should, since it's a collection; if it was a shortcut to `document.querySelector` then there would be no reported length.

Comment: sorry. I meant `querySelector`

Comment: Ok, now I feel dumb :D My script was not loading on the site and I did not notice it, as I am injecting jQuery there with my script... Fail. Thanks for the answers, I did not know that chrome does this.

Comment: if your script is loaded in a different context, you can switch context using the dropdown menu under `Console`

Comment: Nope, it just did not load for some weird reason, after I reloaded the site multiple times, it worked. Thanks for answer. I learn every day some new things :)

Answer (score 1):

I am willing to bet that you do not have jQuery and you are using `$()` in the console.

Type in `jQuery` and you will get an error.

[`$(selector)` dev tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#selector) is a shortcut for `document.querySelector()`

Answer (score -1):

You should be using `$("selector").size()` to check if the element exist.

Comment: No you shouldn't. [It's deprecated as of 1.8](https://api.jquery.com/size/) and `.length` has always been faster.

Comment: A jQuery collection would still report the `lemgth` of the collection.